# Android Studio - Is it mandatory to convert existing project layouts to constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

By converting the layouts how it is going to help in future other than performance(Reducing the hierarchy). Will the support to other layouts will stop?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it mandatory to convert existing project layouts to constraint layout?

No.

> Will the support to other layouts will stop?

Since that will break a couple of million existing Android apps, that is very unlikely. Also, Google still advises using other container classes, in places where they make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Constraint layout is just type of layout like other. But, it reduce hierarchy so, its good if you use it.

> Is it mandatory to convert existing project layouts to constraint
>   layout?

Its not mandatory. Its just a new type of layout.